# Focus in on prepended inputs

Tags: jquery, input, prepend, focusin

I am prepending inputs on a dom element div as shown below:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div onClick="addInputs()">Add inputs</div>
  <div id="inputsContainer"></div>
</div>
<!-- hardcoded inputs -->
<input type="text">
```

```js
function addInputs() {
  $("#inputsContainer").prepend("<input type='text'>");
}

$("input").focusin(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
});
```

This focusin works on hardcoded inputs, but does not trigger on prepended inputs. Let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler as you're appending new `input` elements after the DOM has loaded. Also note that the use of `onclick` is very outdated. I'd strongly suggest using an unobtrusive event handler instead - exactly as you are for the `focusin` event handler

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, thanks buddy. Found the answer there.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working

Comment: One last thought - you can do the style change on focus using CSS alone without need for JS: `input:focus { background-color: #FFC; }`

Comment: @Rory, thing is I need to do some other things on focus-in and focus-out, I wrote the above template just as an example. But thanks.

Comment: Just try this :<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#addInputs").click(function(){
    $("#inputsContainer").prepend("<input type='text'>");
  }); 

$(document).on('focus','input', function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFCC");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div id="addInputs">Add inputs</div>
  <div id="inputsContainer"></div>
</div>
<!-- hardcoded inputs -->
<input type="text">

</body>
</html>

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FS4YFNZ1A8LV